# Android: new text line added to edittext when button is clicked

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, line

I am new to Android :)
What I am trying to do is add a new line of text to edittext whenever the button is pressed.
For example:
you enter in a number (2)
Press the button
EditText displays "you have pressed 2"
when you repeat with a new number (3)
Edit Text will display..
"you have entered 3"
"you have entered 2"

I want it to make a log of the numbers entered in edittext.

I have everything set up already where it displays the line in edittext when the button is entered, I just dont know how to keep the previous line of text, move it to the 2nd line and have the new line on the top.

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're really after, but have you tried concatenating the new string with the existing one and simply put a "\n" inbetween them?

Comment: thanks for the response mate. I did think about concatenating the strings, however I want a whole log to display everytime the button is hit when the user enters a number. So it could have many strings with different numbers. Say users answer = x. It would log ("you have entered" + x) each time the button is hit.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's the issue with that approach exactly? Couldn't you simply do something like `edittext.setText("you have entered " + x + "\n" + edittext.getText().toString())` with each button click? Im assuming at least that you don't ask the user to enter a number in that same EditText... in other words: the `x` comes from some other View, right?

Comment: ok, I found the problem sorta lol. When i used this approach before, it was putting the strings beside eachother rather than a newline. I couldnt tell before because my string was the same length as my edittext box. However, I guess my problem is the \n doesnt move the string to the next line.

Comment: got it to work, had some crap in my edittext in my main. I removed it and is working properly. Thanks again for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure bt it might work

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       for (String s : words){
         builder.append(s+" ");
         tx.setText(builder.toString());
       }
```